# Generating random number with in a range but ignoring some sub range in python

Tags: python

I have a list of say `n` elements(n is even), I want to pick `n/2 + 1` elements from that depending on the generated random number but no number will come more than `n/2` times.

If my list looks like = `[10,30,60,100]` and the generated random number is :`78` then the next highest number from the list will be picked that is `100`.

I am generating random numbers from 1 to 100.

Now suppose the 1st generated random number is: `44`
So the number `60` will get picked.

Now suppose the 2nd generated random number is: `56`
So the number `60` will get picked again.

Now suppose the 3rd generated random number is: `50`
But this time 60 can't be picked as it is already there 2 times which is `n/2`

So now I need to generate random numbers which will be between `1 to 30` and `61 to 100` how can I do it?

I was trying in the below manner:

```
list_ = [10, 20, 30, 40]
print(f"The original list is: {list_}")
cu_list = []
length = len(list_)
cu_list = [sum(list_[0:x:1]) for x in range(0, length+1)]
list1=cu_list[1:]
print(f"The cumulative sum: {list1}")
import random

#random.seed(1) 
x=(random.randint(1, 100))
print(f"Generated random number: {x}")
#list1=[10,20,30,40]
for i in list1:
    if i>x:
        print(i)
        break
```

I didn't add the `n` times loop or `n/2` times condition as I was stuck here unable to think how to generate random number with in those sub range or proceed to this problem in any other manner.

Comment: You can just keep generating numbers in the whole range and retry until you get a last value that gives you a valid output.

Comment: Yeah! I gave this a thought but as I am going to run the loop for (n/2 + 1) times to get those many numbers. So in that case don't you think there are chances of getting less  that (n/2+1) numbers?

Comment: Generate the first n/2 numbers, then loop until the last one gives you a valid output.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. This looks good. One more thing, suppose I have a list of say `N` elements and I want to pick `N` elements from that depending on the same way(random numbers). But no number can come more than `N/2` times. Then also will that approach work? Example : `list = [3,8,15,25,38,53,70,100]`  then one possible output is: `[70,53,70,25,70,70,100,38]`

Comment: If n is large, the probability to have one of the numbers appearing more than n/2 times is extremely low. So,I would just use a `collections.Counter` on the output, check that none of the counts is larger than n/2, and in the extremely rare case where this would happen, just throw away the output and restart the whole process.